# Line to Polygon via Polygonizer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-plugins, linestring, polygonize

My question is in the same vein as this [one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34219/polygonizer-plugin-halts-in-windows).

I'm attempting to convert [precipitation lines](http://www.inegi.org.mx/geo/contenidos/recnat/geologia/infoescala.aspx) (Precipitación Media Anual) to a polygon for Mexico in `QGIS` using the `Polygonizer` plugin.

After running the `Polygonizer` using the `New Method`, it returns the polygon but with a table full of NULL values after clicking `Copy table field from line layer`, the same as [this problem](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43547/problem-with-polygonizer-copying-ids-from-line-shapefile).

The `Old Method` crashes at around 19% completion.

Here's a few related questions to this problem:

Is clipping the lines to smaller sizes the easiest option?

*extracting each line class, polygonize, and then union*

Though I'm unfamiliar with GRASS, is there a way to easily do this?

**EDIT:** I'm going to see if [GRASS](http://lists.maptools.org/pipermail/fwtools/2008-October/001411.html) or [PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/10358/12180) will do the trick

I'm open to any other ways to do this.

Thanks again for all the help!